# Getting database data from server system to mobile app in android using Bluetooth

Tags: android, sql-server-2008, bluetooth

What is a good way to transfer data between SqlServer and android mobile app using Bluetooth.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Bluetooth is very short range-  feet only.  When is your device ever that close to the server?

Comment: this is requirement can you please explain somebody